# Peanut surface is actually not embeddable in Euclidean $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: differential-geometry, arc-length

Although this question arose out of a physics textbook, I believe it is better addressed on math stackexchange.

In Hartle's "Gravity", there was an exposition on differential geometry given. Initially, the text considered the following line element for the sphere:

$$ dS^2 = a^2 (d\theta^2 + \sin^2 \theta\ d\phi^2)$$

Later, the text considered the more general line element

$$ dS^2 = a^2 (d\theta^2 + f^2(\theta)\ d\phi^2)$$

It was computed that:

- the pole-to-pole distance is $a \int_0^\pi d\theta=\pi a$, which is independent of $f(\theta)$
- the circumference of of a circle at constant $\theta$ is $C(\theta)=\int_0^{2\pi} af(\theta)\ d\phi = 2\pi a f(\theta)$

The book then considered the example where $f(\theta)=\sin\theta (1-\frac{3}{4}\sin^2\theta)$. By thinking about how $C(\theta)$ varies (which is something like a smoothened M), the text then claimed that we can represent this geometry by a surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$ that looks like a peanut. See diagram below:

[image: Peanut surface]

However, when I thought further about it, I reached a contradiction. If I fix $\phi$ and travel along the peanut surface from $\theta=0$ to $\theta=\pi$, I don't think that the line element satisfies $dS=a\ d\theta$ on the peanut surface. For one, it is clear that the peanut surface is not at distance $a$ away from the origin at all $\theta$ angles.

1. Am I right to say that this drawing is a simplification to visualise $C(\theta)$ but in reality this geometry is not simply described by a surface like this in Euclidean $\mathbb{R}^3$?
2. Bonus: What functions of $f(\theta)$ will lead to a geometry that can be represented by a surface in Euclidean $\mathbb{R}^3$? If I think about the lengths of paths along fixed $\phi$, it seems that only $f(\theta)=\sin \theta$ (corresponding to $S^2$) works.

Comment: This warp product metric gives the surface of a peanut, just that $\theta$ doesn't take its usual angular meaning but the geodesic distance.

Comment: For your second question, you only get topological cylinders, discs or spheres from the wrap product $I\times_f I$ (basically which endpoints you choose you collapse at $f=0$), and it is clear you want rotational symmetry about some axis for your isometric embedding.

Comment: Am I right to say that as a surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$, the Euclidean distance from top to bottom of peanut (i.e. the vertical line passing through the interior of the peanut) is therefore not actually $2a$? I'm just trying to think how to calculate the equation representing the surface and from your answer, it sounds like the pole isn't going to be at $z=a$.

Comment: Yes, the Euclidean distance between poles is rather nasty (basically you want to solve $y=f(s)$ for a curve on the $yz$-plane).